# MYSQL - JOIN with OR condition

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have 3 Tables CompanyMaster(Which has 3 Million rows), Token1, Token2 and the table structure is,

**CompanyMaster**

```
CREATE TABLE `CompanyMaster` (
  `CompanyUID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `WebDomain` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyPrimaryName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyUID`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3941244 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Token1**

```
CREATE TABLE `Token1`(
  `CompanyUID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Token` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  KEY `Token` (`Token`),
  KEY `CompanyUID` (`CompanyUID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CompanyAlias4_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyUID`) REFERENCES `CompanyMaster` (`CompanyUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Token2**

```
CREATE TABLE `Token2` (
  `CompanyUID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Token` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  KEY `Token` (`Token`),
  KEY `CompanyUID` (`CompanyUID`),
  CONSTRAINT `CompanyAlias5_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyUID`) REFERENCES `CompanyMaster` (`CompanyUID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to get the WebDomain from the CompanyMaster table using the Token1 and Token2 tables.

The Query i am using is,

```
SELECT WebDomain FROM CompanyMaster WHERE CompanyUID IN (
SELECT CompanyUID FROM Token1 WHERE Token='appleinc'
UNION
SELECT CompanyUID FROM Token2 WHERE Token='d012233:q122100:')
```

This query takes almost 30 Seconds to get the result. I executed the sub-query alone, which is taking < 100 milli-seconds.So the problem is with the IN condition.

I replaced the query with join and it is executing in < 200 ms,

```
SELECT c.CompanyUID FROM `CompanyMaster` c
JOIN `Token1` tk1
ON tk1.CompanyUID = c.CompanyUID AND tk1.Token= 'appleinc'
JOIN `Token2` tk2
ON tk2.CompanyUID = c.CompanyUID AND tk2.Token= 'd012233:q122100:'
```

But the problem with above query is , if tk1.Alias = 'appleinc' or tk2.Alias = 'd012233:q122100:' fails it is giving output as empty row. But i want the matched rows even if only one condition is matched.

Please help me how to solve this one ? And i also want the query to be executed in less than 10 milli-seconds. Is it achievable ?

Comment: Did any of the answers fit your needs? Could you leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly get better performance with `UNION ALL` than with `UNION`, as it will have no difference for your case in output, but [it does not need to filter out duplicates like `UNION` does](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php):

```
SELECT     WebDomain 
FROM       CompanyMaster
WHERE      CompanyUID IN
           ( SELECT CompanyUID 
             FROM   Token1
             WHERE  Token = 'appleinc'
             UNION ALL
             SELECT CompanyUID 
             FROM   Token2
             WHERE  Token = 'd012233:q122100:')
```

However, if you would put the `UNION` in the outer query, it might even give better performance, like this:

```
SELECT     WebDomain 
FROM       CompanyMaster m
INNER JOIN Token1 t ON t.CompanyUID = m.CompanyUID
WHERE      Token = 'appleinc'
UNION
SELECT     WebDomain 
FROM       CompanyMaster m
INNER JOIN Token2 t ON t.CompanyUID = m.CompanyUID
WHERE      Token = 'd012233:q122100:'
```

Here it is probably important to only get unique values, so you need `UNION` without `ALL` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause to filter your record on the basis of toke1 and token2. On the basis of your requirement you can change that clause.

Please check following SQL. Hope it will solve your problem.

SELECT 
    c.CompanyUID, c.WebDomain 
FROM 
    `CompanyMaster` c
    LEFT JOIN `Token1` tk1 ON tk1.CompanyUID = c.CompanyUID 
    LEFT JOIN `Token2` tk2 ON tk2.CompanyUID = c.CompanyUID 
WHERE
    tk1.Token = '123' OR tk2.Token = 'xyz';

Comment: Did you test this? This will not give a result for a company when Token1 has '123', but Token2 has no records at all for that company. On the other hand it will give duplicates when Token2 has many records for that company. Also, I have edited your answer to give code-format to the SQL statement. You do this with indenting that block with at least 4 spaces.

Comment: Yes. I did. It is OR clause. One true condition will return the matching company record. One more thing. Yes it will return duplicate records. To avoid that you can use group by clause to find unique records of matching companies.

Comment: It does not work like you say, because you are applying inner joins. Also, it would be nice if you would format your SQL statement as code.